# Need help calling up entry boxes inside defs

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi i'm new to python gui's and have been stumped on this problem for hours. I need to call up a name in an entry box that's inside a def, with another def and keep getting the error:

```
line 15, in callback 
name = (username.get())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Im using the code:

```
from tkinter import *
username = str();
e = object();

def getname():
    global username
    e = Entry(root, textvariable=username)
    e.pack()
    e.focus_set()
    b = Button(root, text = "OK", width = 10, command = callback)
    b.pack()

def callback():
    name = (username.get())
    print(name)

root = Tk()
getname()
mainloop()
```

if i do e.get() it comes up with same error except 'object' instead of 'string'

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: `username` is a string. What is `username.get()` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `username` as `textvariable` of the [`Entry`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112032001/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm), which implies that it is a [Tkinter variable](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112025221/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) such as a `StringVar`. When you change `username` from a string to a StringVar, you can use the `.get()` method that you have. The only thing is that you have to declare it after the creation of the `Tk()` instance because the StringVar is associated to a root:

```
from tkinter import *
e = object()

def getname():
    global username
    e = Entry(root, textvariable=username)
    e.pack()
    e.focus_set()
    b = Button(root, text = "OK", width = 10, command = callback)
    b.pack()

def callback():
    name = (username.get())
    print(name)

root = Tk()
username = StringVar()
getname()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you!! I declared Tk() before making the username = StringVar() and it resolved my issue

Answer (score 1):

You going to have a lot of challenges on how you writing your code, since you beginner to `tkinter` programming i would suggest you do it this way to achieve the same  result.You don't have to declare global variable with this to get the content in the `entry` with this example.

```
from tkinter import *


def callback():
    name = (e.get())
    print(name)

root = Tk()


e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()
b = Button(root, text="OK", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no **username.get()** in python, unfortunately (as there are no get() function, even for string). Maybe this will be work (I haven't tested this yet):

```
def callback():
    global username
    name = username
    print(name)
```

Comment: This question is to do with the `tkinter` module

Comment: But I'm making a solution to the problem he's having @DavidG. Scan Destiro code before voting down

Comment: This does not solve the problem of getting the value from the entry widget.